# How to store different values in different variables in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, for-loop

I have a list as follows: `a = ['abc', 'def']` and I have separate files with these file names which consists of some text inside.

Now I have to extract and save this text from those 2 files inside 2 separate variables in python using a for loop as follows: `c[abc] = text1` & `c[def] = text2`

Here is my code:

```
for b in a:
    x = open('/Users/xyz/'+b+'.txt', 'r')
    c[b] = x.read()
```

But I am getting a name error that `c` is not defined. Can anyone please help me out with this?

Comment: What _is_ this variable `c`, though?

Comment: Well, `c` *isn't* defined. (And if you are getting a `SyntaxError` rather than a `NameError`, you have a different problem.)

Comment: You probably want `c` to be a dictionary. Add `c = {}` before the loop.

Comment: you probably also need `x = open('/Users/xyz/'+ a + '.txt')` or even better use `with open(...) as x: ...`

Comment: @chepner Yes, you were right! I am getting a name error!

Answer (score 0):

1.You have a list a which contains text files.

2.You want to create separate variables to store values of each file.

But this approach which you expect would take lot of unnecessary memory.

3.As per my suggestions you store the values of your text files in to a list and then iterate the list to print the data

```
a=["reverse","abc","def"]
li=[]
for b in a:
    x = open(r"C:\Users\akash\Desktop\dailyChallaneges\\"+b+".txt", "r")
    c = x.read()
    li.append(c)
for ele in li:
    print(ele)
```

OUTPUT:

```
afzdvxdvdxxrfc
saddfgf
cmskjfnzsk.zdnc
```